# How Create Image with pango-view and imagemagick?

Tags: php, imagemagick, pango

I have these codes:

```
 exec('convert -gravity center pango:@1.txt  pango_test.png');
```

and in my txt file i have some text with persian or arabic language.

i tried to create image with imagemagick and nothing...

any help please.

best regards.

Comment: Is Pango installed correctly? Try `convert -list format | grep -i pango`

Comment: it's seems installed correctly, what do this code do?

Comment: The `convert` command gives you a list of which modules are installed and the `grep` command singles out the information about `pango`. It won't change anything on your system, it will just tell me if `pango` is correctly installed.

Comment: Can i use it with  exec('');   ??

Comment: Just run it and show the output.

Answer (score 1):

This is a cairo "toy" related issue, still existing. Some characters (ex. Chinese) are not parsed.